# iPhone provisioning: Certificate does not install key in keychain

Tags: iphone, ios, certificate, provisioning, keychain

I need help:
My profile expired and I can't renew it - don't know why. I deleted everything, set up everything new but nothing worked so far… When I double click the certificate, it will put this one into the keychain under ceritficates, but not install the private and the public key.
Error message is: Xcode could not find a valid private-key/certificate pair for this profile in your keychain.
Does anyone know a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate isn't meant to install the public/private keys; they're not included in the certificate. If you've deleted them and not kept a copy around then you'll need to generate a new pair and resubmit to Apple to generate a new certificate.

Comment: That was also my thought, but it's shown quiet weird in the provisioning assistant. But where do I generate the key? Can't remember and everything looks different than last time I did this :-S

Comment: If you log in to the iOS provisioning portal, select 'Certificates' from the left panel, then the 'How To' tab then there's a walkthrough for creating a certificate signing request (CSR). That'll also generate a private/public key pair. You can then revoke your development certificate and submit the CSR to create a new one tied to the new pair that you'll then have in your keychain.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I now got an App ID for exactly this App. I used to get every App on my phone with just one profile… Is it new to have App Ids?

Comment: I'm not sure if the rules have changed, but the rule was that you could put wildcards in your app IDs, so e.g. you could provision com.clash.* and then use that to run all your com.clash.<whatever> apps.